# trigger advice on a function only when called from a certain other function

Tags: emacs, elisp, advising-functions, defadvice

I am trying to work around the restriction that `dired-do-shell-command` (bound to `!`) cannot be called on current and parent directories `.` and `..`'. The stack-trace is pasted at the bottom.

I can define an advice as below to bypass this error:

```
(defadvice dired-get-filename (before h-no-error-if-not-filep activate)
  (ad-set-arg 1 t))
```

**But this affects all calls to the `dired-get-filename`.** I would like it to trigger only when the stack is `dired-do-shell-command -> dired-get-marked-files -> dired-get-filename`.

The only approaches I can think of are as follows

- Search for matches in `(with-output-to-string (backtrace))` in the advise definition
- Add around advises to the other methods to set some variable which can be tested in the advise definition.

Is there better way to do it? I guess I am looking for access to the current stack-trace as a data structure instead of the string from `(backtrace)`

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Cannot operate on `.' or `..'")
  signal(error ("Cannot operate on `.' or `..'"))
  error("Cannot operate on `.' or `..'")
  dired-get-filename(t)
  dired-get-marked-files(t nil)
  (let ((files (dired-get-marked-files t current-prefix-arg))) (list (dired-read-shell-command (concat "! on " "%s: ") current-prefix-arg files) current-prefix-arg files))
  call-interactively(dired-do-shell-command nil nil)
```

[Why can dired-do-shell-command not operate on '.' or '..'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055903/why-can-dired-do-shell-command-not-operate-on-or)

Comment: For anyone coming to this Q&A late, this issue has been raised and fixed -- `dired-do-shell-command` works on `.` and `..` in the stable release of Emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the stack trace, one layer at a time, via `backtrace-frame`.  But this is really pushing the hack.  I recommend you also `M-x report-emacs-bug` requesting for `!` to work on `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather copy `dired-do-shell-command` to `my:dired-do-shell-command` and from there call `my:dired-get-marked-files` which would call `dired-get-filename` with the third argument t.

This way I copy/paste two functions but I minimize side effects from advising often used functions.

Comment: I would rather *not* copy without a very good reason. I do not know that these functions are often used, but the advise (:)) I derive from your answer is that it is better to avoid `backtrace` since presumably it will be more expensive then adding couple more small advises.

Comment: It's better to avoid defadvice whereever possible.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the stack as a list would be great, but unfortunately that looks like it's inaccessible from elisp. (Edit: Ah, I'm blind; `backtrace-frame` provides this, and I didn't even look at it. Thanks Stefan.)

A similar approach to your second option (of using extra advice and a marker variable) is to just enable or disable the inner advice based on the outer advice. Here's an example:

[emacs follow-mode across frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755737/emacs-follow-mode-across-frames/12772622#12772622)

Comment: Thanks. My first thought was to enable/disable but I will still need a marker variable in the top level function, right?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely file a feature request.

But in the mean you can make your own `my:dired-do-shell-command` without
"copying any code" by using `flet` to rebind `dired-get-filename` only within
your function.  This is close to @oleg's solution.

Also discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150569/save-original-function-locally-rebind-it-with-flet-and-call-original-function-f):

This code is untested, but you get the idea.

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
(defun my:dired-do-shell-command (&rest args)
  (interactive)
  (let ((old-func (symbol-function 'dired-get-filename)))
    (flet ((dired-get-filename (&rest args)
                               (let ((file (funcall old-func 'verbatim)))
                                 (if (memberq file '("." ".."))
                                     (if (car args)
                                         file
                                       (expand-file-name file default-directory))
                                   (apply old-func args)))))
      (apply 'dired-do-shell-command args))))
```

Emacs hackers abuse `defadvice` far too much.  It obfuscates things horribly
and should only be reserved as a last resort solution.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have seen `flet` before but right now `I get No apropos matches for \`flet'`

Comment: you need to load the cl package to get the documentation, I've changed the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `this-command` variable:

```
(defadvice dired-get-filename (before h-no-error-if-not-filep activate)
  (when (equal this-command 'dired-do-shell-command)
    (ad-set-arg 1 t)))
```